# Ignore whitespace within JavaScript quote content

Tags: javascript, html, css, whitespace

```js
document.querySelector( "style" ).innerHTML +=
"html {" +
"  background-color: #0dd;" +
"}";
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
td {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
th:first-child, td:first-child {
  border-left-style: none;
}
th:last-child, td:last-child {
  border-right-style: none;
}
th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
}
th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}
tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom-style: none;
  background-color: #efefef;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ::selection {
        background-color: #0df; color: #0df;
      }
      table, th, td {
        padding: 1rem;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #eee;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      table {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        border-style: none;
      }
      th {
        border-top-style: none;
        border-color: #111;
        background-color: #222;
        color: #fff;
        border-bottom-color: #fff;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr> <th>One</th><th>Two</th><th>Three</th> </tr>
      <tr> <td>four</td> <td>five</td><td>six</td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td>seven</td> <td>eight</td><td>nine</td> </tr>  
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
document.querySelector( "style" ).innerHTML +=
"html {" +
"  background-color: #0dd;" +
"}";
```

I have large contents of HTML/CSS files that I want to "inject" into parts of a webpage like what I'm doing with the `style` tag in this example.

I would prefer to keep these files unchanged like this:

```
document.querySelector( "style" ).innerHTML += "
  html {
    background-color: #0dd;
  }
";
```

Without having to wrap every JavaScript line in quotation marks and adding a + operator at the end of each line.

Do I have to convert all of my code into this format? Or is there a way within JavaScript to add this HTML/CSS code into an element as is; without having to change the format of the original code on a line by line basis?

And The specific CSS and HTML code here is irrelevant. I'm using it just as an example.

Comment: this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @RandyCasburn That's **exactly** what I wanted. Possibly better than I could have imagined. Thank you ^^

Comment: Template literals will work as long as you don't have to support Internet Explorer. I'd love to use them, but too many clients are stuck with IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them.

Using normal strings, you would have to use the following syntax in order to get multi-line strings:

```
console.log('string text line 1\n' +
'string text line 2');
// "string text line 1
// string text line 2"
```

Using template literals, you can do the same like this:

```
console.log(`string text line 1
string text line 2`);
// "string text line 1
// string text line 2"
```

In you case:

```
document.querySelector( "style" ).innerHTML +=
`html { 
  background-color: #0dd;
}`;
```

Comment: Instead of modifiying the HTML-code, you should make use of the CSSStyleSheet API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule